# How can I select with count() on specific user in Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Here is my Database structure: 
[image: DB structure]

Also - there is a table users and reciever_id references that table id. 
I use that query to get count of each type of notifications as well as data for that type of notifications from notification_types table.

```
Notification::
             select('notification_types.*', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
             ->join('notification_types', 'notifications.type_id', '=', 'notification_types.id')
             ->groupBy('notifications.type_id')
             ->get()
```

What I need - is to set constraint on reciever_id, I just don't get - where should I put the where clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just chain the `where` method anywhere before `get`, since your condition will be applied on the `notifications` table:

```php
Notification::select('notification_types.*', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
    ->join('notification_types', 'notifications.type_id', '=', 'notification_types.id')
    ->where('reciever_id', $receiverId)
    ->groupBy('type_id')
    ->get();
```

Also, there's no need with this query to group by `notifications.type_id`, `type_id` will do, because there are no ambiguities created here because there are no other columns named `type_id`.

Comment: damn, I have inserted ->where() before ->select(), why didnt it work and I have to put it before groupBy?

Comment: Actually it doesn't really matter in what order you chain the methods, because the Laravel Query Builder makes sure it builds the query string in the correct order. So you might have just missed something the first time :).